# using blender, how to add armature to svg image object

Tags: rigging, armature, bezier-curves

I have 2d image of a person and converted the same into svg image, uploaded the file into blender and tried to add armature to it but somehow i could not find any relavant controls to bind armature to human shape(svg). How do I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can rig curve objects directly, that is not supported as far as I know. You would have to convert to a mesh before, but topology or meshes converted from curves are generally very bad.

Comment: any other way to convert 2d image into 3d model.....

Comment: Either model it by hand with a quads based topology, can use the SVG curve as guide, or use shape keys in the curve if that is enough.